# Can't bring trait methods into scope

Tags: rust, traits

I have this `lib.rs` file.

```
use std::io::{ Result, Read };

pub trait ReadExt: Read {
    /// Read all bytes until EOF in this source, returning them as a new `Vec`.
    ///
    /// See `read_to_end` for other semantics.
    fn read_into_vec(&mut self) -> Result<Vec<u8>> {
        let mut buf = Vec::new();
        let res = self.read_to_end(&mut buf);
        res.map(|_| buf)
    }

    /// Read all bytes until EOF in this source, returning them as a new buffer.
    ///
    /// See `read_to_string` for other semantics.
    fn read_into_string(&mut self) -> Result<String> {
        let mut buf = String::new();
        let res = self.read_to_string(&mut buf);
        res.map(|_| buf)
    }
}

impl<T> ReadExt for T where T: Read {}
```

And now I want to write tests for it in a separate `test/lib.rs`

```
extern crate readext;

use std::io::{Read,Cursor};
use readext::ReadExt;

#[test]
fn test () {
    let bytes = b"hello";
    let mut input = Cursor::new(bytes);
    let s = input.read_into_string();
    assert_eq!(s, "hello");
}
```

But Rust keeps telling me

type `std::io::cursor::Cursor<&[u8; 5]>` does not implement any method    in scope named `read_into_string`

I don't know why. Obviously I'm `use`ing it already. Confused.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is already in the error:

> type std::io::cursor::Cursor<&[u8; 5]> does not implement any method
>   in scope named read_into_string

The problem is, `Cursor<&[u8; 5]>` does not implement `Read` because the wrapped type is pointer to a fixed-size array instead of a slice, and so it does not implement your trait either. I guess something along these lines should work:

```
#[test]
fn test () {
    let bytes = b"hello";
    let mut input = Cursor::new(bytes as &[u8]);
    let s = input.read_into_string();
    assert_eq!(s, "hello");
}
```

This way `input` is of type `Cursor<&[u8]>` which implements `Read` and so should implement your trait too.